# If you take a 5 foot step out of a threatened square do you provoke an AoO?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I know it says "never provokes an attack of opportunity" so I'm guessing the answer is no, but I wanted to make sure.

Especially in the event there are several enemies and all threatening the square you move out or into.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you don't provoke an AoO by moving *into* a threatened square. It's moving *out* of a threatened square that provokes an AoO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**That's Correct**
Unless an exception applies, you're right. Even when surrounded by a billion dragons and Tiamat herself 5-ft. steps don't provoke attacks of opportunity. It says so right [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Take-5-Foot-Step):

> You can move 5 feet in any round when you don't perform any other kind of movement. Taking this 5-foot step never provokes an attack of opportunity.

**...And There's an Exception**
The feat [Pin Down](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/pin-down-combat) requires a minimum fighter level of 11 and the feat Combat Reflexes,  but its benefit reads

> Whenever an opponent you threaten takes a 5-foot step or uses the withdraw action, that opponent provokes an attack of opportunity from you. If the attack hits, you deal no damage, but the targeted creature is prevented from making the move action that granted a 5-foot step or the withdraw action and does not move.

I'd totally give *at least* one dragon 11 fighter levels and the feat Pin Down.

Comment: There's also a maneuver, Guard's Oath (Eternal Guardian discipline) in the beta for the upcoming Path of War 2, which allows an exception, similar to Pin Down. It does require a setup (you have to land the maneuver first, then the target becomes vulnerable to your AoOs when 5-foot-stepping), but it takes only a single class level, rather than 11, and that level can be in something a lot more useful than Fighter. (You can also get it from a feat if your BAB is at least +3, and that feat *is* eligible to be a fighter bonus feat, in case you really want to go with fighter for that one level.)